# Symfony validators, widgets for backend

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-forms

I use symfony 1.4.8 . I add ReCaptcha to my form , using SfExtraFormPlugin. I have widget and validator for it in my  **" public function configure() "**

```
....     
$this->widgetSchema['captcha'] = new sfWidgetFormReCaptcha(array(
      'public_key' => sfConfig::get('app_recaptcha_public_key')
    ));


$this->validatorSchema['captcha'] = new sfValidatorReCaptcha(array(
      'private_key' => sfConfig::get('app_recaptcha_private_key')
    ));
...
```

I also have backend app , and my **"public function configure()"** for it :

```
 public function configure()
  {
    parent::configure();
....
}
```

So when I want to add post from my backend I have an  error:***The item has not been saved due to some errors.***
Is there a way to remove widget and validators for ReCaptcha only to my backend? Now I see only one way, it is to remove

**parent::configure();**

and write all widget and validators to backend separately  from the frontend  widget and validators.. :(
p.s Sorry for my bad English
p.p.s Thank you in advance for your answers ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an option to your form. When you instantiate it, you should know if you're on the backend or the frontend.

```
// in your actions.class.php
$this->form = new MyForm(null, array('from_backend' => true)); // or false...

// in your form
if (!$this->getOption('from_backend'))
{
  // add the recaptcha widget and validator...
}
```

It should work :)

Answer (score 0):

I find  second way :

```
if ( sfConfig::get('sf_app') == "frontend" )
{
   widget and validator
}
elseif ( sfConfig::get('sf_app') == "backend" )
{
   widget and validator
}
```

Comment: This way is not recommended. Your form is not supposed to know the environment. It's the controller's job to tell him.